# Unity UI Input Simulator - Drag events won't work on canvas other than Overlay

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, simulation, drag

i'm currently creating a plugin for input simulation in Unity 5.5.1f1. During the creation I found out that if the UI objects that i'm sending scroll or drag events, on a Canvas different from Overlay will not work properly, the event keep sending the value to 1 of the scroll/slider . It work's just fine on a Overlay Canvas.
Anyone know a workaround?

```
 PointerEventData __newPointerEventData = new PointerEventData(null);
 __newPointerEventData.position = p_screenPosition;

 ExcuteEvents.Execute(gameObject, __newPointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.scrollHandler);
 ExcuteEvents.Execute(gameObject, __newPointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);
```

Comment: Did you attach the main camera to the Canvas's Renver Camera slot?

Comment: Yet, I did, the result are the same with or without the camera.

Comment: I try to change some configs on the camera but it didn't worked as well